# Export properties prefix line with servername for appended log

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I want to run a PowerShell script on each individual server so it appends to a csv

I need values "server name", service, servicename, startname, startmode in one line so it can be filtered by "server name" etc in excel

I got this far...

```
$computername = $env:computername
$computername | Get-WmiObject win32_service | select $computername,name, startname, startmode | Export-Csv c:\temp\export.csv
```

But it does not add `servername` to each line.

Answer (score 1):

you were on the right track. How's something like this?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select -property name,startname,startmode,__server | Export-csv \\server1\blah\file.csv -append
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a list of *properties* to display on the screen. `$computername` is not a property name but a *value* that you are trying to add to the column.

You need to add that property and populate it. A couple simple ways to address that. First would be create a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for `ServerName` like you were describing above. We also clean up how you are passing the `$computername` to the function.

```psh
Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computername | select @{Name="ServerName";Expression={$computername}},name, startname, startmode
```

You can also use the cmdlet `Add-Member` to the same thing.

```psh
Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computername | 
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $computername -PassThru | 
        select servername, name, startname, startmode
```

Or you can create a custom object (Not the approach I would take for this since it is mostly redundant but is included for completion).

```psh
Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $computername | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{
        "server name" = $computername
        "name" = $_.name
        "start name" = $_.startname
        "start mode" = $_.startmode
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props

} | select "Server Name",name, "start name", "start mode"
```

**There is a simpler option as well**

As [bundyfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30432613/3829407) points out there is a property `__SERVER` that is returned with the `System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_TerminalService` object that you could use as well.

If you are remoting and want to retain whatever friendly name you have for computer name use one of the option above. Else you can just use `__SERVER` in your `Select` statement